# R-squared equivalent for Generalized Estimating Equations (GEE) using a ordinal logistic regression model

Tags: r-squared, effect-size, generalized-estimating-equations, ordered-logit

Is there a measure that shows how well GEE using a ordinal logistic regression model explains the amount of variance in the data?

Answer (score 3):

Five years late, but yes (kind of). Zheng proposed two $R^2$ analogues for GEE in 2000 (citation at bottom of answer).

#### Option 1

For your ordinal logistic model, assume that there is an underlying continuous latent variable that, when thresholds are applied, results in your observed ordinal $Y$.  (Also assume that your software allows you to access that latent variable.)

Run a second GEE predicting that latent variable with the same predictors used in the ordinal model.  From there, you can use Zheng's marginal $R^2$:

$R_{marginal}^2 = 1- \frac{\sum_{c=1}^C \sum_{i=1}^N  (Y_{ic} - \widehat {Y_{it}})^2}  {\sum_{c=1}^C \sum_{i=1}^N  (Y_{ic} - \bar Y)^2}         $

where the numerator is the sum of the squares of the Y (your latent variable) minus the fitted values from this second GEE across each cluster ( $c_1, c_2, ... c_C$ ) and each observation ($i_1, i_2, ... i_N$ ), and the denominator is the sum of the squares of the Y (your latent variable) minus the marginal mean of that Y.

#### Option 2

Ignore the ordered nature of your outcome variable and use Zheng's $H_{marginal}$ as a measure of "proportional reduction in entropy due to the model" where your model becomes a multinomial logistic model.  $H_{marginal}$ is defined as

$H_{marginal} = 1 - \frac{\sum_{c=1}^C \sum_{i=1}^N  \sum_{k=1}^K \hat \pi_{cik} 
 log(\hat \pi_{cik})  }  { nT\sum_{k=1}^K \hat \alpha_k  log(\hat \alpha_k) }         $

where $ \pi_{ck}  = P( Y_c = k | X) $ is the "model-based probability that a categorical response [in cluster $c$] equals $k$",  $\alpha_k = P(Y = k)$ is "the marginal probability of response $k$", and hats (^) indicate estimates.

Note that for both $R_{marginal}$ and $H_{marginal}$, you can obtain a "negative value when there is greater uncertainty in prediction under the model of than under the null model".

[Zheng, B. (2000). Summarizing the goodness of fit of generalized linear models for longitudinal data. Statistics in Medicine, 19(10), 1265-1275. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1097-0258(20000530)19:10<1265::AID-SIM486>3.0.CO;2-U](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/(SICI)1097-0258(20000530)19:10%3C1265::AID-SIM486%3E3.0.CO;2-U)

Comment: @JRF1111 this isn't straight forward for me so I thought I'd try to write it out in R::geepack for a general & logistic (not at ordinal yet) GEE. Please tell me if I've understood you correctly. I'm kind of confused by the idea of running a second GEE to predict fitted values of the first. It seems like that should perform perfectly and in testing it has. Have I misunderstood something? I've posted the code @ https://github.com/bkellman/GEEreport/blob/master/reportFunctions.r

Comment: @gung a related approach is to evaluate the predictive ability of a GEE. I’ve created a new R package doing just that using proper scoring rules: https://drizopoulos.github.io/cvGEE/

Comment: @DimitrisRizopoulos, it isn't my approach, that was a botched attempt to convert an answer to a comment.  Hopefully, it's correct now.

Comment: is it possible to use the second option for a continuse response variable?